# Group by with an order/ range notion

Tags: mysql, sql

I work with mySql and I face a problem.
I have the following records in my table Task

```
idTask | User | Task  | Step
-----------------------------
1      |   1  | Task1 |  1
2      |   1  | Task2 |  2
3      |   2  | Task3 |  3
4      |   1  | Task4 |  4
5      |   1  | Task5 |  5
```

I would like to retrieve data in that recordset:

```
 User 
--------
   1  
   2  
   1
```

A group by on User doesn't respect the order and give me the following result.

```
 User 
--------
   1  
   2
```

Is that possible with a simple query or not?

Comment: What is the query you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky.  Somehow, you need to identify when a user is different from the previous one.

Here is one method.  It uses a correlated subquery to identify the number of users before a given user that are different.  This assigns a grouping to the users, which can be used for the `group by`:

```
select user
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from task t2
              where t2.idtask <= t.idtask and t2.user <> t.user
             ) as grp
      from task t
     ) t
group by grp, user
order by min(id);
```

Comment: Very clever solution! Thanks Gordon.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard 'sequence starts and ends' pattern:

```
SELECT a.step start
     , MIN(c.step) end 
     , a.user
  FROM my_table a
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table b 
    ON b.user = a.user 
   AND b.step= a.step - 1
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table c 
    ON c.user = a.user 
   AND c.step >= a.step
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table d 
    ON d.user = c.user
   AND d.step = c.step + 1
 WHERE b.user IS NULL 
   AND c.user IS NOT NULL
   AND d.user IS NULL
 GROUP 
    BY a.step, a.user;
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution which perfectly works, I prefer the gordon's answer that is more easily readable.

Comment: Note that both solutions are likely to be deathly slow on large data sets - not sure what to do about that.

Comment: Yes, I notice that too, but the table shouldn't be huge ( < 5000 lines)